# Значення: "вітка" = "гілка"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, іменники

У [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/vitka) знаходжу:

> **ВІ́ТКА,** и, жін.
>
> 1. Зменш. до **віта**→**ВІ́ТА** див. **віти**→ **ВІ́ТИ**, віт, мн. (одн. віта, и, жін.). Відгалуження дерева, куща або трав'янистої рослини; **гілки**.
>
> **ГІ́ЛКА,** и, жін. Невеликий боковий відросток, пагін дерева, чагарника або трав'янистої рослини.

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghilka).

А у [Словнику В. Жайворонка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0) знаходжу:

> **гі́лка = ві́тка = ві́та (мн. ві́ти)**.

Отже, чи **гілка=вітка**, чи є якісь особливості їхнього вживання?

Answer (score 1):

Словник синонімів Караванського подає ці слова як синоніми, а також інші лексеми того ж ряду:

[ВІТИ](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53394/262940.html) 
мн., гілки, галузки, віття, галуззя, гілля, пагілля; вітоньки, віточки.

Answer (score 0):

Згідно до [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0) "вітка" або "віта" - це діалектна назва "гілки". Також у ці два слова є [синонімами](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0).